# Creating a line with circle in the middle

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

So, I'm trying to achieve this result:

[image: line with circle in the middle]

This is what I got when I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/wvdkmjge/

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, I want that I'll not see the border line on the circle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nice one OP. You say **I want that no border line on the circle**, and add **`border: solid 1px black;`**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A small amendment to your code to `position` the elements and you get the effect you want to achieve.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
.blue {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #3EB2EF;
}
.blue .circle {
  background: #3EB2EF;
  border-color: #3EB2EF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container blue">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I cant do it now, just more 4 minutes

Comment: thanks for this elegant solution. How have you found " top: -6px;" please?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to position an element depending on its parent, use `position:relative` for the parent and then add position relative or absolute to the child. to center something in the middle, use `margin:0 auto` and if it has absolute positioning also add `left:0; right:0;`

https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/e4ev3awj/1/

```css
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:relative;
}
.circle {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background:blue;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="circle">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

a bit late to answer, but this looks like a typical `<hr/>` that needs some makup.

```css
/* restyle however your needs are hr and its pseudo elements , here only one is used */
hr {
  color: turquoise;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
}
hr:before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: turquoise;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -10px;
  box-shadow: inherit
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Comment: Thats a better option. Why unnecessarily increase no of elements. `<hr>` seems semantically correct too here.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/wFq6r/245/)

This uses a lot of different codes then above.

```
class:before and class:after
```

Hope this helps you!